# Prevent UIGestureRecognizer from firing selector more than once

Tags: cocoa-touch, ipad

I utilize a UILongPressGestureRecognizer in my app. This is a continuous gesture recognizer which means it continuously fires the selector for the target it was initialized with. I would like the selector to be fired only once. I have tried to prevent further selectors being fired by setting the gesture recognizer's enabled property to Note the first time the selector is fired, but this only takes effect after the selector is fired again. How can I ensure the selector is fired only once?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not been able to find a way to force the selector to be fired only once. The workaround I have employed is to set the gesture recognizer's enabled property to NO after the first time it fires and then to re-enable it when necessary.

Answer (score 2):

The selector will be fired repeatedly; just only act from within it if `[sender state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan`.

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately it's six months late. I hope Run Loop figured this out on his own. This is the safe, non-side-effecty way of doing it. :)